# How to convert latitude and longitude from decimal dms to degree in java

Tags: java, google-maps, dictionary, gps, latitude-longitude

I receive the latitude and longitude from a GPS with this format:

Latitude: 3328.21103S 
Longitude: 07043.64734W

I need convert this data to:

Latitude: -33.4701838
Longitude: -70.7274557

How to convert this data in java?

Thanks .

Best Regards.

Comment: Get the last index of the input string and use that to determine wheter or not you need the negative sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this way:

1- Separate lattitude and longitude in degree, minutes, seconds, direction(N,S,W,E)

2- Send degree, minutes, seconds, direction to method DMSaDecimal this return: latitude or longitude in decimal

```
public double DMSaDecimal(int grados, int minutos, double segundos, String direccion) {

    double decimal = Math.signum(grados) * (Math.abs(grados) + (minutos / 60.0) + (segundos / 3600.0));

    //reverse for south or west coordinates; north is assumed
    if (direccion.equals("S") || direccion.equals("W")) {
        decimal *= -1;
    }

    return decimal;
}

public String[] SeparararDMS(String coordenada, int type) {

    String grados = null;
    String minutos = null;
    String segundos = null;
    String direccion = null;


    switch (type) {
        case 1: // latitude
            grados = coordenada.substring(0, 2);
            minutos = coordenada.substring(2, 4);
            segundos = coordenada.substring(5, coordenada.length() - 1);
            break;
        case 2: // longitude
            grados = coordenada.substring(0, 3);
            minutos = coordenada.substring(3, 5);
            segundos = coordenada.substring(6, coordenada.length() - 1);
            break;
        default:

    }

    double sec = 0;
    try {
        sec = Double.parseDouble("0."+segundos);
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }


    sec = (sec * 60);
    direccion = coordenada.substring(coordenada.length() - 1);

    String[] data = {grados, minutos, sec + "", direccion};
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I think, it is antipattern to not use English language

Answer (score 0):

Using [arcgis](http://www.arcgis.com/):

```
public static void convertCoordDMS(){
    try{
        // create coordinate object for degrees, minutes, seconds format
        DMSCoordinate dmsCoord = new DMSCoordinate();
        dmsCoord.setString("37 -123 32 34.43"); // put a string value
        String dms = dmsCoord.getString(); // get back the normalized DMS string
        System.out.println("Input (string): (\"37 -123 32 34.43\")");
        System.out.println("Output (normalized string): " + dms + '\n');

        // now for decimal degrees
        DDCoordinate ddCoord = new DDCoordinate();
        // put in the Point from dmsCoord. The Point property is
        // “common ground” for all Coordinate objects
        IPoint point = null;
        ddCoord.setPoint(dmsCoord.getPoint());

        // get back the normalized DD string
        String dd = ddCoord.getString();
        System.out.println("Input (Point): same as DMS");
        System.out.println("Output (normalized string): " + dd + '\n');

        // and the coordinate as lon lat doubles 
        double[] x = new double[25];
        double[] y = new double[25];
        ddCoord.getCoords(x, y);
        System.out.println("Input (Point): same as DMS");
        System.out.println("Output (Lat Lon): " + x + " " + y);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you're interested in knowing more, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) is a good place to start.